# Do automatic battles end your turn in Neuroshima Hex?

Tags: neuroshima-hex

Your turn ends if you start a battle by playing a Battle Tile. Does starting a battle by filling the board also end your turn?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it does. A battle will always end the turn. From the [3.0 rules](http://portalgames.pl/new_en/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/EN_Neuroshima_Hex_3_0_rulebook.pdf):

> The player who starts a Battle (by playing Battle tile or filling up the board)
>   finishes his turn, regardless of the number of tiles he has left. As soon as the
>   Battle commences, no other tiles can be used or even discarded.

It's also the way it is implemented in the mobile app (I've checked, forcing the described situation).

Comment: Ah, glad they've clarified this in the newer rulebook. And thanks for checking the app as well :)